# Show that the function is bijective in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H$ be a normal finite subgroup of $G$, and $g \in G$ has an order $n$. The only elements in $H$ that commutative to $g$ is only its identity element $e$. 
>   Show that a map $f: H \mapsto H$, $f$ is defined by $f(h) = g^{-1}h^{-1}gh$ is a bijection.

We must show that $f$ is injective and surjective. I don't know how to start honestly. We have stripped over paper but don't found exact solution. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The condition precisely tells you that it is injective, and the subgroup is finite.

Comment: How do you know that it is injective?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's enough for the map to be either injective or surjective, since it's a function from a finite set to itself.

Injection: Suppose $f(x) = f(y)$. Then $g^{-1} x^{-1} g x = g^{-1} y^{-1} g y$, so $x^{-1} g x = y^{-1} g y$, and hence $(xy^{-1})^{-1} g (xy^{-1}) = g$.

The step which gets you that final equality is one that it's well worth learning: it's a manipulation which turns up all the time.

Comment: Injection: if $f(x) = f(y) then $x = y$? How does this?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy What is unclear about what I wrote?

Comment: How do we prove that $x =y$?

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy What is unclear about what I wrote?

Comment: Ah i got it. Thanks!